# Bulk create in related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-related-manager

I have 2 models in my app -

In models/parent.py I have -

```
 from django.db import models
 class Parent(models.Model): 
       class Meta:
          db_table = "parent_table"
       start_date = models.DateField()
       end_date = models.DateField()
```

In models/child.py I have -

```
from django.db import models
from models.parent import Parent
class Child(models.Model): 
   class Meta:
      db_table = "child_table"
   some_ref = models.ForeignField(Parent)
```

We can do single insert into child table using the parent table reference as -

```
self.child_set.create(**args)
```

Is there a way by which we can do bulk insert into related table, as the normal [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Are the objects already stored in the database?

Comment: Slightly different from the question you asked (and maybe I'm misunderstanding), but I just set the related object myself and then use `bulk_create`.  Something like `new_children = [Child(*child_args, parent=me) for child_args in SOME_LIST]` followed by `Child.objects.bulk_create(new_children)`.